# What is 無茶はなし here?

Tags: meaning

It's a pep talk of commander before the important operation.

とにかく勝ち目のない無茶はなしだ！ 誰も犬死になんかさせたくない！

I think 無茶はなし= 無茶はない, so the sentence would be

"Anyway, they don't stand a chance, that's for sure!"

But maybe 無茶はなし= 無茶(な)話?

Comment: I'd translate. Don't push too hard unless you have a chance to win! I don' want anyone to die for nothing! 無茶: do something to the extreme extent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

無茶 here is a noun that refers to unreasonable/reckless/extreme things. This はなし is the topic marker followed by [this 無し](http://%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%A0%20is). ～はなしだ means "No ～!" or "Don't ～!". 無茶はなしだ means "No reckless actions!" or "Never do reckless things!".

勝ち目のない modifies 無茶 as a (gap-less) relative clause.